# Format another cell based on this cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible based on current cell value, format another cell? Maybe I am overcomplicating things, but what I need to achieve is to display a message in a cell if the file is in Protected Mode. Once a user clicks "Enable Editing" this message should disappear. So what I thought of doing is have a cell set to the message. Then have another cell change this is cell if some calculation is correct. Since it won't be able to calculate until Editing is enabled, the message will display. And once a user Enables Editing, the message will be gone. Is there a direct way to do this or a workaround that will do the trick.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes. It doesn't do the trick, unless I should use it differently. The way I tried it was: have a cell color set to red. Then if 2+2=4 set the color to white (which is same as background). The cell doesn't show anything (or shows in white, hard to say)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Still using conditional formatting. I set the value of another cell to a formula (=2+2) and then in my cell check if the value is 4 then change format. Guess could do the same with the IF. Just needed to think from a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using an IF formula?

```
=IF(cell=correct,"","Displayed Message")
```

You can replace the cell=correct with your condition check that you mentioned in your post.
Leave the next set of quotes blank (so if that condition is met no message will appear)
Change the contents of "Displayed Message" to whatever you want to display if your condition is not correct ie. your sheet is in protected mode.